# dimplejs line series tooltip customisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, data-visualization, dimple.js

I have this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ra2xS/38/. I have made few attempts to customise the tooltip so I can hide few data attributes from the tooltip but completely failed.

Can anyone please help me to hide the "date" from the line series tooltip?

```
    var dim = {"width":590,"height":450}; //chart container width
var data = [{"date":"01-02-2010","cost":"11.415679194952766"},{"date":"01-03-2010","cost":"10.81875691467018"},{"date":"01-04-2010","cost":"12.710197879070897"}];


function barplot(id,dim,data)
{
    keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
    var xcord = keys[0];
    var ycord = keys[1];
    var svg = dimple.newSvg(id, dim.width, dim.height);
    var parser = d3.time.format("%d-%m-%Y")
    var dateReader = function (d) { return parser.parse(d[xcord]); }
    var start = d3.time.month.offset(d3.min(data, dateReader), -1);
    var end = d3.time.month.offset(d3.max(data, dateReader), 1);

    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg,data);
    myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 505, 305);        

    //var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", xcord);
    var x = myChart.addTimeAxis("x", xcord, "%d-%m-%Y","%b %Y");
    x.overrideMin = start;
    x.overrideMax = end;
    x.addOrderRule(xcord);
    x.showGridlines = true;
    x.timePeriod = d3.time.months;
    x.floatingBarWidth = 100;

    var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", ycord);
    y.showGridlines = true;
    y.tickFormat = ',.1f';    

    var s1 = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
    var s2 = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
    s2.lineWeight = 3;
    s2.lineMarkers = true;

    var s3 = myChart.addSeries("Price Break", dimple.plot.line);
    s3.data = [
        { "Price Break" : "high", "cost" : 12.71, "date" : parser(start) }, 
        { "Price Break" : "high", "cost" : 12.71, "date" : parser(end) },
        { "Price Break" : "avg", "cost" : 11.65, "date" : parser(start) }, 
        { "Price Break" : "avg", "cost" : 11.65, "date" : parser(end) },
        { "Price Break" : "low", "cost" : 10.82, "date" : parser(start) }, 
        { "Price Break" : "low", "cost" : 10.82, "date" : parser(end) }
    ];

    myChart.draw(1500);

}

barplot("body",dim,data);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In version 2 you can put whatever you like in the tooltip. Here's an example of how:

http://dimplejs.org/adhoc_viewer.html?id=adhoc_bar_custom_tooltips